# How to count amount of times partial string appears in list?

Tags: python, list, count

Say I have a list and I want to count how many times a partial string appears "AB" Is there a way to make count() work? I want to try and make this as efficient as possible without breaking the code down into a loop.

```
my_list = ["ABC", "ABD", "DCF", "ARC", "AVB", "ABG"]
```

Correct output = 3

Comment: You have to check every item in the list so a loop (explicit or hidden) is essential

Comment: What did you try yourself? This is not a hard problem

Comment: Ah dam it, I can do it in a loop just was hoping there was something as quick as the .count() function

Comment: list.count() still loops under the hood, but it's fast because of the C-implementation

Comment: No need to use count! Just use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63512656/13811930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it into a string and use `str.count`:

```
>>> my_list = ["ABC", "ABD", "DCF", "ARC", "AVB", "ABG"]
>>> ' '.join(my_list).count('AB')
3
```

Or use `sum` and a comprehension:

```
>>> sum(s.count('AB') for s in my_list)
3
```

Comment: Notice I'm joining by a space

Comment: @Chris_Rands That isn't a problem.  Even so, I think I prefer `sum(1 for i in my_list if "AB" in i)` to converting it to a string.

Comment: OP wanted a solution without a loop

Comment: `str.join()` does loop

Comment: @alaniwi though to match the letter of the question you must do `[str(bool("AB" in i)) for i in my_list].count("True")`,  `</kappa>`

Comment: You're going to have to iterate over the list in one form or other - the requirement is totally arbitrary.

Comment: Why do we need count always? You can do it without using count : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63512656/13811930

Comment: @HaardikDharma Because if theres more than 1 `'AB'` in a string it will account for them otherwise it will only count one.

Comment: @Jab I see, gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

What is your expected behavior for `["ABAB"]`?  Do you want `2` or `1`?  If you want `2`, you will still get value out of "count".

```
sum(s.count("AB") for s in my_list)
```

That being said, your problem seems poorly defined, what if your string is "AA", how many do you expect for `["AAA", "AA", "A"]`?  1 (exact)? 2 (per item)? 3 (all possible ranges)?

Answer (score 3):

Loop through each element as follows:

```
sum(1 for i in my_list if "AB" in i)
```

Or a longer alternative:

```
count = 0
for i in my_list:
    if "AB" in my_list[i]: count+=1
```

Note: I know the OP *doesn't* want to loop but I don't think it's possible without one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sum built-in function. In your case,

```
my_list = ["ABC", "ABD", "DCF", "ARC", "AVB", "ABG"]
sum('AB' in s for s in my_list)
```

Output: 3

This code works because booleans can be treated as integers. Each time 'AB' appears in a string element, True is returned. The integer value of True is 1. So it's as if each time 'AB' is in a string, 1 is returned. Thus, summing the 1's returned will yield the number of times 1 appeared in an element.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a huge list that hurts time efficiency, you can parallelize this.

- Initialize a globalCounter
- Split the list into n chunks
- For each chunk, spawn a thread and send it to a function that internally runs a loop to count "AB" occurrence in that chunk
- Let every thread update the globalCounter
- When all the thread finish execution, return the globalCounter as result

Although this still effectively loops through the entire list, parallelization improves the time.